# POST request triggers both THEN and CATCH

Tags: ajax, vue.js, post

I have this submit function below to save an article.

My response code is 200 in browser but it triggers both **then** success branch and the **catch** error. I don't understand why.

my article is saved correctly

from my browser log as you can see I get both 1 and 3 console.log() :

```
[Log] 1 (src_vue_component_role_common_article_add_vue-f9ecfd1edc9c94aaed1b.js, line 243)
[Log] 3 (src_vue_component_role_common_article_add_vue-f9ecfd1edc9c94aaed1b.js, line 259)
[Error] LOG – "There was an error: " – ""
    Error (src_vue_component_role_common_article_articles-editor_vue-f9ecfd1edc9c94aaed1b.js:1560)
    (anonymous function) (src_vue_component_role_common_article_add_vue-f9ecfd1edc9c94aaed1b.js:260)
```

```
submit() {
        if (this.validate()) {
          let formData = this.$refs["media-manager-" + this.uid]
            ? this.$refs["media-manager-" + this.uid].getFormData()
            : new FormData();
          formData.append("article", JSON.stringify(this.article));

          this.loading = true;
          let context = this;
          this.progress = 0;
          axios
            .post(this.articlePath, formData, {
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
              onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
                context.progress = Math.round(
                  (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
                );
              },
            })
            .then((response) => {
              const data = response.data;

              if (data.success) {
                console.log(1);
                toastr.success("article saved", null, {
                  positionClass: Storage.preferences.nPos,
                });
                const article = JSON.parse(data.article);
                this.$emit("saved", article);
                this.loading = false;
                document.getElementById("contentPad").scrollIntoView();
                this.progress = 0;
              } else {
                console.log(2);
                Error(response);
                this.loading = false;
                this.progress = 0;
              }
            })
            .catch((response) => {
              console.log(3);
              Error(response);
              this.loading = false;
              this.progress = 0;
            });
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if your `Data.success` is true. If it comes as undefined in your data, it is going to go into the else block and call `Error`.

Please check the data being sent